# Magento Adding Total Due and Total Paid to PDF invoice

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Hi I am trying to add total paid and total due lines on my Magento PDF Invoice. I have added these lines in the config file in sales/etc/config.xml.

```
<pdf>
        <invoice>
            <default>sales/order_pdf_items_invoice_default</default>
            <grouped>sales/order_pdf_items_invoice_grouped</grouped>
        </invoice>
        <shipment>
            <default>sales/order_pdf_items_shipment_default</default>
        </shipment>
        <creditmemo>
            <default>sales/order_pdf_items_creditmemo_default</default>
            <grouped>sales/order_pdf_items_creditmemo_grouped</grouped>
        </creditmemo>
        <totals>
            <subtotal translate="title">
                <title>Subtotal</title>
                <source_field>subtotal</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            </subtotal>
            <discount translate="title">
                <title>Discount</title>
                <source_field>discount_amount</source_field>
                <amount_prefix></amount_prefix>
                <title_source_field>discount_description</title_source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
            </discount>
            <shipping translate="title">
                <title>Shipping</title>
                <source_field>shipping_amount</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>400</sort_order>
            </shipping>
            <adjustment_positive translate="title">
                <title>Adjustment Refund</title>
                <source_field>adjustment_positive</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>500</sort_order>
            </adjustment_positive>
            <adjustment_negative translate="title">
                <title>Adjustment Fee</title>
                <source_field>adjustment_negative</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>600</sort_order>
            </adjustment_negative>
            <grand_total translate="title">
                <title>Grand Total</title>
                <source_field>grand_total</source_field>
                <font_size>8</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>700</sort_order>
            </grand_total>
            <base_total_due translate="title">
                <title>Total Due</title>
                <source_field>base_total_due</source_field>
                <font_size>8</font_size>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>800</sort_order>
            </base_total_due>
            <total_paid translate="title">
                <title>Total Paid</title>
                <source_field>total_paid</source_field>
                <font_size>8</font_size>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>900</sort_order>
            </total_paid>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
```

This gives me the lines I need in the PDF invoice but the values are 0. Theses values are in the database table sales_flat_order but it is looking for them in sales_flat_invoice. I have also made a mysql column in sales_flat_invoice and manually input a number and it shows up on the invoice so I know this will work. My question is how can i call the column from a different table in the config file or how can i input the total paid and total due values into two new columns in my database?

this is the code for the block in the order page that displays the total due and total paid.

```
protected function _initTotals()
{
    parent::_initTotals();
    $this->_totals['paid'] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'code'      => 'paid',
        'strong'    => true,
        'value'     => $this->getSource()->getTotalPaid(),
        'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalPaid(),
        'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Paid'),
        'area'      => 'footer'
    ));
    $this->_totals['refunded'] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'code'      => 'refunded',
        'strong'    => true,
        'value'     => $this->getSource()->getTotalRefunded(),
        'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalRefunded(),
        'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Refunded'),
        'area'      => 'footer'
    ));
    $this->_totals['due'] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'code'      => 'due',
        'strong'    => true,
        'value'     => $this->getSource()->getTotalDue(),
        'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalDue(),
        'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Totaal Due'),
        'area'      => 'footer'
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share the solution, if you were able to do it.

Comment: can you pls share how you added paid and due fields in to pdf